# setting defaultChecked in radio button is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I need to set the defaultChecked on page load which can later be changed by the user

```
<input
  ref={(element) => (this['input' + item.key] = element)}
  name={item.key}
  placeholder='Config value'
  defaultChecked={item.value === true}
  value='true'
  type='radio'
  onChange={(event) => this.validateCValue(event.target.value, item)}
/>
<label> True</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radio inputs can only be checked but not unchecked, if you set it to true, the user will not be able to uncheck it, maybe you meant to use a checkbox?

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(checked => !checked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Config value"
        defaultChecked={checked}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <label>{checked ? "checked" : "not checked"}</label>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks .. defaultChecked={checked} this line helped me understand on what i was doing wrong..now it worked

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I encountered a similar problem, after hours of trial and error, I simply had to change my code from
`defaultChecked={value === 'string'}` to `defaultChecked={value === 'string' ? "true" : "false"}`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me use "checked" tp set radio button default value

```
<div onChange={this.sethandleValueChange.bind(this)} className={` ${(this.state.IsControlSet && this.state.RadioBtnVal=="" ? styles.control_border_red : "")}`}>
<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="RadioBtnVal" checked={this.state.RadioBtnVal=="Yes"} disabled={(this.state.FormName!="View") ? false : true}/> Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" value="No" name="RadioBtnVal" checked={this.state.RadioBtnVal==="No"} disabled={(this.state.FormName!="View") ? false : true}/> No
</div>
```